# Nested where statement using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I am attempting to run a simple query in PowerBI using python. Sadly, most python libraries are not supported in PowerBI, so I'm limited to pandas and numpy. The dataset is a set of projects that are either in pipeline or active. I want to filter the dataset down to rows that are just in pipeline based on a set of or conditions. So it would like look

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(where project = 'Pipeline'), set of other conditions to filter pipeline launches by)

Is that possible in python, similar to a nested where statement?

Comment: Python can do nearly everything. There are many frameworks in AI that may help you. in any case I don't think stackoverflow is the place for such  question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` to lookup multiple values in a column. If you want to filter based on multiple columns then you need to chain you `loc` or `iloc` conditions. Basically whatever you get returned from a iloc or loc is also a dataframe, below is the working example of both conditions.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'col3': ['NULL','NULL', np.nan, 'virgo']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

We will query the dataframe to get rows where col3 is either `virgo` or `NULL`

```
>>> df.loc[df['col3'].isin(['virgo','NULL'])]
   col1  col2   col3
0     1     3   NULL
1     2     4   NULL
3     3     6  virgo
```

Now we will query the dataframe to get rows where col3 is `NULL` and col2 is `4`

```
>>> df.loc[df['col3'] == 'NULL'].loc[df['col2'] == 4]
   col1  col2  col3
1     2     4  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If all conditions in one variable do:

```
df [ df.column_name.isin([value_1, value_2, value_n]) ]
```

if conditions in multiple columns do

```
df [ (df.column_1 == "value_1") & (df.column_2 == "value_2") & (df.column_n.isin([val_1, val_2, val_3])) ]
```

Note:
`&` means `AND`, so if both (left and right) are True the result is `True`, else result `False`.

if you need `OR` condition use `|`.